# Store dynamically created objects in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have to create a game. I have Player class that is abstract. I have a GameEngine class that has a dynamic array of pointers to Player. Whenever a player is added I classify it and create a Mage or Hero object (both children of Player) in a "addPlayer()" method in GameEngine. However, after the method finishes the pointer is destroyed and if I try to access that item in the players array it crashes with "segmentation fault". I know why this is happening but I don't know how to work around. I'm not even sure if that's the right way to get this done. Can you give me advice? Thanks :)

EDIT

This is some sample code:

```
class GameEngine {
    ...
    Player** players;
    ...
    void addPlayer() {
        Hero h("Frodo");
        players[playerCount] = &h;
        playerCount++;
    }
}

class Player { ... }
class Hero : public Player { ... }
```

Comment: if you want help with code you need to show code. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: For objects that are to live beyond their scope you could manage them via `std::shared_ptr` and store those in a container for later access.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
class Player
{
  public:  
    virtual std::string& get_name() const = 0;
};

class GameEngine
{
  public:  
    std::vector<Player *> m_players;

    void  add_player(Player * p)
    {
      m_players.push_back(p);
    }
};
```

The above is the essence of your question.  The `add_player` adds a player to your database.

A broader view:

```
class Shaman
: public Player
{
  std::string m_name;
  public:
    virtual std::string& get_name() const
    {
       return m_name;
    }
  Shaman()
    : m_name("Bubba")
  { ; }
};
```

The above is an example class derived from `Player`.

Code fragment to create a dynamic instance and add to the `GameEngine`:

```
Shaman * p_bubba = new Shaman;
GameEngine game;
game.add_player(p_bubba);
```

Remember that `GameEngine` class only knows about the public functions and members in `Player`.  C++ has no internal facilities for fetching the type name of the child types in the `m_player` database.  My recommendation is to provide all the functions that `GameEngine` **needs to know** in the `Player` class and let the descendants implement those functions.

Comment: This works but the program asks the user what type of player it should add and in the add method it parses the input to determine what type was given by the user. After that a corresponding player object is created. For example if the user types: “add shaman” the parser will detect the type and create a Shaman object. If I add its pointer to the array, and try to access it later it gives the error, because the pointer was destroyed after the method had finished.